# How to manage uninitialized input signals

Tags: simulation, vhdl, modelsim, hardware-design

I would like to know your opinion on how to test and manage input signals of a component that are 'U', 'X', '-', ...

For example, if I want the output to be 'X' for all non-valid inputs, where at least one bit of the input isn't '0' or '1':

```
entity foo is
    port (
        signal inp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal outp: std_logic );
end entity foo;

architecture bar of foo is
begin
    process(inp)
        if (inp < "11001010") then
            outp <= '1';
        else
            outp <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture bar;
```

This way, the test defaults to being false.

How would be a general way to test the inputs?

Comment: BTW, your `inp < "11001010"` suggests you are using the non-standard `std_logic_unsigned` or `std_logic_arith` packages from Synopsis that are erroneously stuffed into the ieee library. The correct alternative is `ieee.numeric_std`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Is_X` from [`std_logic_1164`](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/std_logic_1164.vhdl); it will return `true` if your `std_logic_vector` contains any of 'U', 'X', 'Z', 'W', '-'.

`Is_X` will always return `false` during synthesis (you can e.g. use `Is_X('W')` to test whether you're in simulation or synthesis.)